# Why can't I kill viber using terminal?

Tags: command-line, kill, viber

I can't kill viber process in terminal.

```
$ pkill Viber
```

or

```
$ pgrep Viber 
2849
$ kill 2849
```

or

```
$ killall -v Viber
Killed Viber(2849) with signal 15
```

do not work.

But in System Monitor choosing "Kill Process" from the right-click menu will kill it.

Answer (score 6):

Type `killall -9 viber`.

1. A `SIGTERM` or a *signal 15* allows a process to end gracefully.
2. A `SIGKILL` or a *signal 9* kills the process immediately.

By default, `kill` and `killall` will send a `SIGTERM`, so the process should end in a few seconds, but if a process is completely unresponsive, you can specify `SIGKILL` which will kill the process immediately:

*Use `SIGKILL` only as a **last resort.***

The `-v` or `--verbose` option asks `killall` to be more elaborate on what it's doing. Hence it says it tried to kill the process with a signal 15, i.e `SIGTERM`.

Read more about the signals [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm)

Comment: Just a note to others reading this: Some people tend to use `kill -9` as their usual method of killing a process, but it is better to try just `kill` ("TERM" signal) without the `-9` first, to give it a chance to do any data cleanups or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have to kill Viber, not viber. Had the same problem and was wondering why. Running `killall -9 Viber` would be best.